How do you (correctly) call C++ Windows DLL functions if you do not have a corresponding header?
I have a piece of specialized, expensive hardware that does some specialized things (it's a CMM arm).
It has the normal, really really terrible super-special-purpose software, and I'd like to be able to take data with the thing without having to use their tools.
Digging around, there is a small(ish) demo application that I can run that talks to the hardware, and it uses a DLL that looks to expose basically everything I need. However, it's a C++ dll, and I'm confounded trying to figure out the proper way to call functions from it, as what the actual proper way to call class member functions through a DLL (and therefore effectively a void*) barrier.
Throwing the DLL into dumpbin gives me a lot of things that look exactly like what I want:
public: __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::Client(void) __ptr64
public: __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::Client(class SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client const & __ptr64) __ptr64
public: virtual __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::~Client(void) __ptr64
public: enum SomeComapny::Cds::Api::eCDSReturnCode __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::ControlArmMeasurementStream(struct SomeComapny::Cds::Api::sCDSArmMeasurementStreamConfig const & __ptr64)const __ptr64
public: bool __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::IsConnectedToServer(void)const __ptr64
public: bool __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::IsServerAvailable(void)const __ptr64
public: enum SomeComapny::Cds::Api::eCDSReturnCode __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::GetInstrumentConfiguration(void)const __ptr64
public: enum SomeComapny::Cds::Api::eCDSReturnCode __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::GetInstrumentData(void)const __ptr64
public: enum SomeComapny::Cds::Api::eCDSReturnCode __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::StartMeasurement(void)const __ptr64

<snip several hundred lines>

I can use LoadLibrary() to load the DLL, and then I have a table that maps function names to ordinals so I can get the address of individual functions via FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(this->lib_ptr, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(func_ordinal));, but at that point I'm stuck.
For instance:
public: __cdecl SomeComapny::Cds::Api::Client::Client(void) __ptr64 is obviously a constructor. How do constructors work if you just have a pointer to it? Constructors don't normally have a return type, and how would the application calling the DLL handle a return anyways given I don't know exactly how large the object is?
Experimentally, the function appears to both return a value, and require it be passed a pointer where it then writes a bunch of things (I think vtables?). I think the return value may just be an error, but guidance on precisely how c++ types map down to the actual machine operations is hard to find.
Also, how would virtual functions (there are some) work in this context?

In C you can allocate a buffer with the correct size then call the constructor with the mangled name and pass this pointer, knowing the size and alignment of the buffer is one problem, and if they as much as make a private member public you have to start over because the layout and size changed.

Or you can try contacting them about providing you with a programming API, most companies will be glad to ship you a C dll to automate their devices (sometimes at an extra cost)

Or you could reverse engineer the demo app, which tends to be expressly forbidden by EULAs, which in turn tend to be overruled by things like interoperability exceptions. Not legal advice, but check with lawyers before proceeding.

Don't wast your time on something that is near to impossible. Contact the manufacturer and ask for the full support API and documentation.

Please don't try to XY problem the question, AhmedAEK, @OldBoy. If this was a work thing, that would absolutely be the correct thing to do. However, this is a hobby project, I'm using it as an excuse to teach myself reverse-engineering, and I can't afford to spend more for API access then I did to buy the silly thing second hand on ebay.

If you know which compiler was used (probably some ancient version of VS) you can generate an import library from the DLL and recreate the class yourself. Study the calls to the constructor in the demo app to see how large eg Client is and add a char unknown[X] as sole member. That should be sufficient to create a Client object. Now you can start adding methods to it. The alternative is a small asm stub that calls selected functions with the object in ECX (or RDI on x64)

Alternatively, you could also investigate the external effects of the DLL and reverse engineer the protocol it speaks with the device, whether USB or IP.

As for virtual functions: the constructor is responsible for writing the vtable pointer into the object.

@Botje - yeah, I figured that out by calling the constructor with a pointer into the middle of a buffer filled with known values. It looks like it writes multiple separate vtables (I know this class uses inheritance pretty heavily).  Where I'm stuck is understanding how the compiler maps virtual functions to a vtable offset - is it just by  the order which the virtual functions are defined in the class body?

WRT decoding the protocol - I've also looked into that, but it's equally annoying. It uses SendMessage() and GetMessage() from winuser.h (implemented in user32.dll) to do inter-process communication with the server, and as far as I can tell there's no tool out there to spy on that particular interface. I can see a few places in the DLL where it's doing the messaging, but it's several layers of dynamic dispatch down in ghidra (see the complex inheritance noted in the previous comment), and the logic is very difficult to follow.

There may be better tooling for reversing the messaging stuff, but unfortunately "window message(es)" is basically impossible to search effeciently. It doesn't help that there's a completely different suite of functions called "Microsoft Message Queuing" (MSMQ) which is completely unrelated.

At this point we are well into reverseengineering.stackexchange.com territory but: 1) yes, function offsets in a vtable follow the order in which they were declared. Note that vtables also include offsets for virtual functions in any base classes.
2) You could use the well-known  Detours library to hook SendMessage and GetMessage, printing the message's contents before passing it through to the demo application

@Botje - Fair point, I forgot reverseengineering.stackexchange.com exists. Also, I just found Spy++ and/or winspector, which looks like it will let me monitor messages.

Oh, not to drive you away. But the audience there has much more (targeted) experience in REing.

I flagged this to see if it can get migrated.
